# Draggable widget blocks scroll gesture

Tags: flutter, dart, scroll, draggable, gesture

I have a tree structure like the following, basically a `Row` inside a `SingleChildScrollView`, where the children of the `Row` are `Draggables`.

```
Positioned(
          top: 250,
          left: 30,
          child: Container(
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: initialState.map((f) => LongPressDraggable(
                  child: f,
                  feedback: Transform.scale(scale: 0.4, child: f),
                  childWhenDragging: Container(),
                )).toList(),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
```

The problem is that the Draggable seems to be consuming any gesture, so that, when tapping (long press in this case), the drag effect works, but no other gesture seems to work, so basically scroll does not respond.

I tried using, instead of LongPressDraggable, a regular Draggable and use `affinity` property, but even with that, the scroll does not respond, just the drag.

Any help or suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else dealing with this (at the end stupid situation)....

It turns out that the **problem does NOT come from the `Draggable`** itself.....

For some reason, putting the `SingleChildScrollView` inside a `Positioned` prevents this from scrolling....

Found a clue in this bug: [bug report](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/36584)

So that, the solution proposed in the bug about giving double values to the top, bottom, left, right properties of the `Positioned` did not work well for me.

So...I solved it by using exactly the same code, but **using `Align` widget instead of `Positioned`.**